# Spring Cacheput is not updating the existing cache

Tags: java, spring, redis

Im working with redis + spring and try to update a existing cache

```
@Cacheable(value = "project")
public Project getProjectById(BigDecimal id){...}

@Caching(put = { @CachePut(value = "project", key = "#projectModel.id")})
public Project updateProject(Project projectModel)
{...}
```

Note:- Cacheable is working fine, only cacheput is not working.

Comment: can you elaborate by giving sample values or how you are calling these methods?

Comment: I'm doing the following:
First i'm calling the getProjectById method;
After that i'm making a change in the project and calling another method

Comment: is the change reflecting say database? can you show your impl of these methods

Comment: yes, the change reflecting in my database.

Comment: you need to show the implementation of the updateProject. we need to see what is being returned by this method

Comment: Had you tried debugging your logs? Does Project implement serializable? Also you can use CachePut directly without putting in the Caching annotation.